# How do I have Safari (v12) auto download PDF files

Tags: safari, pdf

On previous versions of Safari, I have been able to auto download PDF files by using the following code in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool YES
```

When I got a new MacBook Air running Safari 12, this option no longer works.  Does anyone know of a solution while still using Safari.  I run a lot of reports that I need to download and not just view.

Answer (score -1):

The Acrobat/Reader plug-in for Apple Safari is based on **Netscape Plug-In API (NPAPI)**, which is supported only till Safari version 11. [In Safari 12, support for NPAPI plug-ins](https://developer.apple.com/safari/whats-new/) is removed, and hence the current Acrobat/Reader plug-in will not work. For detailed information, please refer to help articles [Display PDF in browser Adobe Acrobat, Acrobat Reader](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html#id_48998)

What’s New in Safari - Apple Developer

Source: [Adobe.com](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2538731)

Comment: If they removed it, why when I upgraded in my MacBook Pro does it still work?